# Black spots developing on flat-coated retriever tongue

Tags: dogs, health

I have a 2 and a half year old flat coated retriever boy, who has started to develop black spots on his tongue slowly over the last six months or so. He has a larger one about the size of a pound coin far back, and two smaller ones about pea-sized near the tip, and they are completely flat on his tongue.

I know that black-spot birthmarks on the tongue are quite common in retrievers and are usually just extra pigment, and my dog's spots look identical to images of these birthmarks I have seen online. However my dog's spots have not been here since birth, can these birthmarks appear this late, or is this something I should get checked out by a vet?

He hasn't changed any behaviour with his tongue or general life at all, is showing no signs of pain in the slightest.

Many thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't seem to find a good reference for you right this minute but I can speak from experience. I've had dogs pigment continue to change up to six years old. It happens more dramatically and faster when they are young. If it really is a pigment change from pink to black and there isn't any raised area there is nothing to worry about.